# Сущность не добавляется в базу данных через Entity Framework. "column "Id" of relation "vip_clients" does not exist"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

**Пытаюсь добавить в базу данных сущность VipClient.**

Вот диаграмма базы данных:
[image: Imgur]

Модель:

```
public class VipClient
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Маппинг :

```
public class VipClientMap : IMappingEntity<VipClient>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<VipClient> builder)
    {
        builder.ForNpgsqlToTable("vip_clients", "clients");
        builder.HasKey(entity => entity.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(entity => entity.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("vip_client_id");

        builder
            .Property(entity => entity.Comment)
            .HasColumnName("vip_client_comment")
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(entity => entity.CreationTime)
            .HasColumnName("creation_time")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Во время добавления в базу данных выдается такое исключение.
[image: Imgur]

Есть подозрение что дело в маппинге(писал не я)

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос. Ваше исключение даже не читается на этой картинке.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Текст исключения - "column "Id" of relation "vip_clients" does not exist"